# How to return a dictionary with increasing swap using bubblesort to sort a list of random integers?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to return a similar output in the doctest but when the function is called, I get the amount of times the item has been swapped and also the sorted list.

I tried creating a variable for an empty dictionary and tried to include the returned function inside, but I do not know how to.

```py
def bubbleSort(numList):

    num_dict = {}

    for j in range(1, len(numList)):

        swap_check = False

        for i in range(len(numList)-1):

            if numList[i] > numList[i + 1]:
                numList[i], numList[i + 1] = numList[i + 1], numList[i]

                swap_check = True

                return numList
        if swap_check == False:
            break
    return j, numList
```

expected result:
        Takes a list and returns 2 values
        1st returned value: a dictionary with the state of the list after each complete pass of bubble sort
        2nd returned value: the sorted list

```
>>> bubbleSort([9,3,5,4,1,67,78])
({1: [3, 5, 4, 1, 9, 67, 78], 2: [3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 67, 78], 3: [3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78], 4: [1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78], 5: [1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78]}, [1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78])
```

Actual result:

```
>>> bubbleSort([9,3,5,4,1,67,78])
(5, [1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78])
```

Answer (score 1):

So the reason you got `(5, [1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78])` as your output is because the last time through the loop `j` = 5 and `[1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78]` is your sorted list which is what you are returning from your function. `return j, numList`

We can use your `num_dict` dictionary to store the results of the sorting algorithm as we iterate through the list.

`num_dict[j] = num_list[:]`

Because we are mutating `num_list` I make a copy of the list when we store the result of the sort in `num_dict`. `num_list[:]` just returns a copy of `num_list`.

Here it is in the completed function:

```py
def bubble_sort(num_list):

    num_dict = {}

    for j in range(1, len(num_list)):
        swap_check = False

        for i in range(len(num_list)-1):
            if num_list[i] > num_list[i + 1]:
                num_list[i], num_list[i + 1] = num_list[i + 1], num_list[i]
                swap_check = True

        # store result of sort iteration
        num_dict[j] = num_list[:]

        if swap_check == False:
            break

    return num_dict, num_list
```

And now we get this when we run the `bubble_sort` function:

```
>>> bubble_sort([9,3,5,4,1,67,78])
({1: [3, 5, 4, 1, 9, 67, 78],
  2: [3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 67, 78],
  3: [3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78],
  4: [1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78],
  5: [1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78]},
 [1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78])
```

Comment: Of course. If it helped you, would you mind marking my solution as the answer?